# Two textviews make the right textview one line and no ellipsis the left will fill the extra area and can be mutliple lines

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create two `textviews`.  one aligned left and one aligned right.  I want The one on the right to be in one line and ,have an ellipsis and always show the full text.  The left would just fill the remaining area until it reaches the right `textview` and then it goes to the second line.

So my goal is to have a display like below

> ```
>  |this is a test     MY Date|
>  |title that can            |
>  |be as many lines          |
>  |as they want              |
> ```

Below is what it looks like with my below code:

> ```
> |this is a test title MY...|
> |that can be as many       |
> |lines as they want        |
> ```

I could theoretically make the right textiview a static width.  But I for sure do not want the left textview to be a static width as I want it to change according to the view size.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_title"
    android:text="@string/widget_text" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingRight="70dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="5dp"
    style="@style/TextViewShadow"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_date"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="5dp"
    style="@style/TextViewShadow"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am struggling to figure out how to do this.  I am sure it's just some concept I am missing.  Please reply with a layout example I could use to test or at least something to look into or a tutorial.

Comment: @David-- IF you found the fix, as u said so plz post it as answer instead of as a part of question.
It will help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below seems to be the fix:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/widget_layout">
<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_date"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="24sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:padding="5dp"
style="@style/TextViewShadow"
android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_title"
android:text="@string/widget_text" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:textSize="24sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:padding="5dp"
style="@style/TextViewShadow"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/widget_date"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `android:layout_width="200dp"` the widget_title textview and the work is done ;)

Comment: I think that is hardcoding the widget_title width which is not what I want to do.  I am ok with hardcoding the widget_date but not the widget_title

Comment: then you have to set the both widths (for the widget_date and the widget_title) to "fill_parent" or "match_parent"

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply.  Just getting around to working on this.  My goal is to have the right textview wrap the content.  THen the left textview fill the rest of the area.  With your last comment it just makes them equal size.  I am working on it now.  Hopefully will have a fix tonight

Comment: I found a fix and posted it at top.  Thanks for your help